# How to average an entire column but ignoring the header

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I feel like this should be simple and my notation is just wrong, I know if i want to sum the entire column I can use this formula:

```
=AVERAGEIF(C:C, "<> ")
```

(I'm using "<>" as i need to ignore blanks)

How do i offset it by one row? I want it to start at C2 bu excel doesn't like

```
=AVERAGEIF(C2:C, "<> ")
```

Many thanks!

Comment: is the header a number?  if it is text it does ignore it.

Comment: Also `AVERAGE(C$2:C$1048576)` will ignore all the blank cells, no need for AVERAGEIF().

Comment: Why 1048576? Is that the max number of rows on a sheet?

Comment: Yes for a .xlsx.

Answer (score 3):

AVERAGE ignores text and blanks so,

```
=average(c:c)
```

... should be the same as,

```
=averageif(c2:index(c:c, match(1e99, c:c)), "<>")
```

(unless the header in C1 is numeric)